# Close popup after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, popup, submit

That seems to be a common question with multiple replies but I couldn't get any of them work.

I'm working on WP. Currently I'm using a plugin that shows a pop-up as soon as a not logged in user lands to the website. In the popup I use an optin form (created through MailChimp).
When the user submits his info, a new tab opens moving him to the email verification page.

The problem is that the popup remains open in the first tab.

I would like it to close as soon as the data are submitted. Is that possible?

Here's a [link](http://deals.karditsa.topgreekgyms.gr) to the website.

Here's the code of my form:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">  
<form action="http://fitnessforum.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d6acf8949532b107b7b21c9d0&amp;id=1304ea7322" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">

<div class="mc-field-group">
<input id="firstname3" style="width:260px;margin:5px 0;background-position:95% center" type="text" value="" name="FNAME" placeholder="'Ονομα">
</div>

<div class="mc-field-group">
<input id="primaryemail3" style="width:260px;margin:5px 0;background-position:97% center" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email">
</div>

<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div> 

<div class="clearfix">                  
<input name="subscribe" style="width:305px;margin:4px 5px 0 0" class="simplemodal-close button_link hover_fade large_button silver button_widget" type="submit" value="ΣΤΕΙΛΤΕ ΤΟ ΔΩΡΟ ΜΟΥ!"></div>
</form>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center">
<p class="under_button2"> Το email σου είναι ασφαλές στα χέρια μας.</p>

<div class="af-clear">
</div>

</div>
</div>                  
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: Closing it from the the popup should work by `window.close()` or from the page that opened the popup like `var popup = window.open(...); popup.close()`

Comment: Also pay attention, that many browsers come with the setting "scripts are not allowed to close windows" being on by default

Comment: @MarcellFülöp how can I add this function? The button looks like this: "<input name="subscribe" class="button_link hover_fade large_button silver" type="submit" value="ΣΤΕΙΛΤΕ ΤΟ ΔΩΡΟ ΜΟΥ!">"

Comment: Can you show some code? It'd be easier to point out the right way/place to add a line that closes that popup.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I have added the code of my form and a link to my website. I hope that helps.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, also without giving a flick to comment, I wish would do web forms in popups with vanilla javascript in his/her whole life!... :-p

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your "thank you" page has code like *someone above* is mentioning. Is it an actual popup or javascript one like shadowbox? You might need something like this:

parent.Shadowbox.close();"

Comment: the popup is actually generated through the plugin. It's generated through javascript and I used css to create a see-through background.
Could you elaborate a little bit more on what you're suggesting?

Comment: Try and find out what "box" code they are using. Most people don't code those from scratch (even plugin developers) so it will be: Shadowbox, Lightwindow, etc. It's probably one of those. So you'll need to find out how to manually close the window with just a piece of code like above, and have that run when you submit the form. If it's a big nasty plugin might be hard to do all that. Good luck.